# How to right justify backbutton on NavigationView header line?

Tags: c#, uwp

Here's my first attempt, except the problem with this one is that the header is above the commandbar, not in the same row.

```
    <NavigationView
                    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                    IsBackEnabled="False"
                    Header="MyHeader!"
                    x:Name="NavView">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Globe" Content="Item1"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <CommandBar>
                <AppBarButton Icon="back"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="forward"/>
            </CommandBar>
            <Frame Row="0" x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
        </Grid>            

    </NavigationView>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Here's the way I solved it:

```
    <NavigationView
                    Background="{ThemeResource 
                         SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}"
                    IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                    IsBackEnabled="False"
                    Header="Zobz!"
                    x:Name="NavView" 
                    SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home"  Content="Home"  /> 
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Globe"  Content="Item1"  />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CommandBar>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Back"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Forward"/>

                    <CommandBar.Content>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="appTitle"
                              FontSize="20"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </CommandBar.Content>
                    </CommandBar>
            </DataTemplate>
        </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>

        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>

    </NavigationView>
```

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.